# Do SDL surfaces get reused?

Tags: sdl

In SDL, lets say I'm rendering text to a surface. Then I blit it with the scene's main surface to form a composite image to flip.

I get the text surface into a class-level member called 'messageSurface':

```
messageSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid( ..... );
```

So, do I have to call

```
SDL_FreeSurface(messageSurface);
```

on every loop to prevent memory leaks? Or will SDL "reuse" the old surface the next time around?

Comment: Whether it's class-level or not makes no difference. TTF_RenderText_Solid creates a new object and returns a pointer to it, and assignment in C++ overwrites the old value, so you no longer have a reference to the previous surface, meaning it will leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation here:

http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_43.html

the pointer returned is to a new surface. So yes, you need to free the surface to avoid memory leaks.

Offhand, that seems a rather odd API design. Instead, I would have expected you to pass an allocated surface to the function.

Comment: It's impractical to know what size surface you'd have to pass in.

Comment: More impractical than reallocating bunch of surfaces each frame? I do get your point, though. I would have given several options.

Comment: If the text doesn't change, just use the same surface.